# Geometry nodes - how to get a vector of the bottom right corner of the bounding box?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to use the "Set position" node to change the pivot of the text to the bottom right corner, but I have no idea how to get this offset vector, because the "Bounding Box" node returns only the bottom left and top right vectors.
Thank you for your suggestions.

[image: Bounding Box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution for a two-dimensional shape would be to simply recombine the components of the vectors.

For example, you can solve it like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for great ideas :)